# Let $I$ be an Interval, let $f\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, Then $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I$ be an Interval, let $f\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $c$, Then $f$ is continuous at $c$.

This is a theorem from my first course real analysis class. I know i must use the definitions of derivative and of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

First, $\;f(c)\;$ exists as we need it in the definition of $\;f'(c)\;$ , and second

$$f'(c):=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{|f(x)-f(c)|}{x-c}\implies\;\forall\;\epsilon>0\;\exists\,\delta>0\;\;s.t.$$

$$|x-c|<\delta\implies \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|<\epsilon\implies$$

$$|f(x)-f(c)|\le\epsilon |f'(c)||x-c|\xrightarrow[x\to c]{}0$$